# Java/C++ sum of a n number of elements

Tags: java, c++, sum, numbers, pseudocode

I have a code , for a program which calculate a sum of a n numbers, but this is having a little catch, for the n=4, the would be like this,sum=1*2+1*2*3+1*2*3*4.I've started with a for, but suddenly the output is nearly to the reality, but still far:)). I don't want to be the target of programmer jokes :)). So help me understand the concept behind this ...I'm still far away from the answer.

Comment: You need two loops, one inside the other.

Comment: Did you make an attempt?

Comment: @Jason of course i do...but my idea wasn't as good as I was thinking

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well, no for? only 2 loops?

Comment: May be this will help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-of-the-series-1-12-123-1234-1234-n/

Comment: What will be the answer for n=1?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it

Answer (score 0):

You can try running below code -> 
Try understanding the logic

your Method should go this way

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int n = 4;
    int sum = 0;
    int mul = 1;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=2;j<=i;j++)
        {
            mul = mul * j;
        }
        sum = sum+mul;
        mul=1;
    }


    System.out.println("the answer is " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code also :

```
    sum=0;pro=1;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++){   //Since you did not mentioned the answer for n=1...
        pro = pro * i;   // this will be like 2 , 2*3 , 2*3*4 ... so on at each step
        sum += pro;
    }
    cout<<sum;
```

It can be done in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might do it in java 8. Granted if n < 2 then this wont work.

```java
      int result = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n)
              .map(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, x).reduce(1, (first, second) -> first * second))
              .sum();
```